# PHP MySQL Two queries

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to Know how can I in PHP code, execute two mysql query (query_1 and query_2) but display only the results of query_2 for each result of query_1 like that :

```
query_1==> `SELECT tbl_name FROM table_ref `

query_2 ==> `SELECT id,name FROM (result of the first query)`
```

query_1 return the names of tables : table1, table2, table3, and with the query_2 I have to do this :

`SELECT id,name FROM table1` and `SELECT id,name FROM table2` ... as in a loop

Thanks in advance for your advice !

Comment: Hope tbl_name is not tablename :) Not getting crazy :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, name FROM sometable WHERE name in (SELECT tbl_name FROM table_ref)
```

In this example there need to be a connection between 2 tables

Comment: yeah but that's not quite what I need, because `sometable` comes from the second query which follow `IN` in your code

Answer (score 0):

On php side, you can deal with both the aray results as foll:

```
$array1 = array('tbl_name1' => '' ,'tbl_name2' => '');

$array2 = array('tbl_name1' => array('id' => 'id1'),
                'tbl_name2' => array('id' => 'id2'));

echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_intersect_key($array2, $array1));
echo '</pre>';
```

o/p:

```
Array
(
    [tbl_name1] => Array
        (
            [id] => id1
        )

    [tbl_name2] => Array
        (
            [id] => id2
        )

)
```

Comment: but how do i put the two queries together, especially that there is a lot of results

Comment: array1 => result of query1, array2 => result of query2

Comment: I don't see where do you include query1 in query2, I need something like : `SELECT id,name FROM (SELECT tbl_name FROM table_ref )`

Comment: quer1 return the names of tables : table1, table2, table3, and with the query2 I have to do this : `SELECT id,name FROM table1` and `SELECT id,name FROM table2`and ... as in a loop